# UIView Animation not working - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiview, uiimageview

I am trying to animate a simple UIImageView, but it is not working. Here is my code:

In my header file, I have declared "light_bulb" as a UIImageView.

```
NSMutableArray *bulb_off_images = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (int loop = 0; loop < 11; loop++) {

    if (loop >= 10) {
        [bulb_off_images addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"bulb_off-%d.png", loop]]];
    }

    else {
        [bulb_off_images addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"bulb_off-0%d.png", loop]]];
    }
}

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:2.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
    light_bulb.animationImages = bulb_off_images;

} completion:^(BOOL finished){

    if (finished) {
        NSLog(@"Finished !!!!!");
    }
}];
```

The code seems to run and the completion block is called but the animation does not happen.....

**Update 1 **

I tried doing the animation this way, but I need a way of stopping the animation from repeating itself. How do I know when to call "stopAnimating". Here is my code:

```
light_bulb.animationImages = bulb_off_images;
light_bulb.animationDuration = 0.5;
light_bulb.animationRepeatCount = 0;
[light_bulb startAnimating];
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can't animate a property change that has no effect on the UI. I'm going to go out on a limb and say you have some fundamental misunderstandings as to how these classes operate. Read the docs ([UIView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html), [UIImageView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiimageview_class/Reference/Reference.html)), they will help you.

Comment: You can do this far more easily if you read image view's class reference.

Comment: @esqew I updated my answer with another method of doing the animation which works, however my problem now is that I can't stop the animation from repeating itself.

Comment: If you had read the documentation like I had suggested, you would know that, for `animationRepeatCount`, *"The default value is 0, which specifies to repeat the animation indefinitely."*

Comment: @esqew Ah right. I am the complete lazy idiot here. I was under the impression that 0 meant that it would run once and then not repeat. Thanks for your help. If you put that in an answer, I will be happy to tick it sir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In regards to your original question, you're over-complicating your solution. [`UIImageView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiimageview_class/Reference/Reference.html) has animation methods built-in. It looks like you're trying to use them in conjunction with `UIView`'s animation features, which won't work exactly the way you're planning. Review the docs for each, and decide which classes' animation features you would like to use.

(For images, `UIImageView`'s animation methods seem to be the preferred way to go.)

---

As for your second question: in the [documentation for `UIImageView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiimageview_class/Reference/Reference.html), the notes for `animationRepeatCount` state:

> The default value is 0, which specifies to repeat the animation indefinitely.

Setting your `animationRepeatCount` to 1 should play the animation only once.